# Difficulties in creating update with Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, oop, laravel-5.1, eloquent

I'm trying to create an update with Laravel 5.1 but it shows the error:

I have 2 updates in this method and I noticed that the error already happens in the first one

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::update() must be of the type
>   array, null given

My **Controller**

```
 public function update($id)
{


        $dadosForm = $this->request->except('_token');
        $dadosForm = $this->request->offsetUnset('fat_cnpj');
        $dadosForm = $this->request->offsetUnset('vatendimento');
        $dadosForm = $this->request->offsetUnset('integra');
        $dadosForm = $this->request->offsetUnset('material'); 

    $proposta = $this->proposta;

        $proposta->cliente_id = $this->request->get('cliente_id');
        $proposta->contato = $this->request->get('contato');
        $proposta->email = $this->request->get('email');
        $proposta->telefone = $this->request->get('telefone');
        $proposta->fatcnpj = $this->request->get('fatcnpj');
        $proposta->atendimento = $this->request->get('atendimento');
        $proposta->dt_solicitacao = $this->request->get('dt_solicitacao');
        $proposta->dt_vigencia = $this->request->get('dt_vigencia');
        $proposta->vendedor = $this->request->get('vendedor');
        $proposta->coleta = $this->request->get('coleta');
        $proposta->dt_integracao = $this->request->get('dt_integracao');
        $proposta->hr_integracao = $this->request->get('hr_integracao');
        $proposta->frete_material = $this->request->get('frete_material');
        $proposta->status_id = $this->request->get('status_id');  

        $this->proposta->where('id', $id)->update($dadosForm);




        $proposta_id = $id;

        $count = $this->ensaios->max('id');


        for($i=1;$i<=$count;$i++){ //Save Ensaios

        $proposta_ensaios = new PropostaEnsaios();

        $proposta_ensaios->id_proposta = $proposta_id;
        $proposta_ensaios->id_produto = $i;
        $proposta_ensaios->quantidade = $dadosForm['quantidade_'.$i];
        $proposta_ensaios->valor= $dadosForm['valor_'.$i];
        $proposta_ensaios->total = $dadosForm['total_'.$i];

        $proposta_ensaios->where('id', $id)->update($dadosForm);

        } 


    $this->request->session()->flash('alert-success', 'Dados Alterados com Sucesso!');
    return redirect()->route('manage-content');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the $dadosForm variable to NULL in the last four lines of:

```
    $dadosForm = $this->request->except('_token');
    $dadosForm = $this->request->offsetUnset('fat_cnpj');
    $dadosForm = $this->request->offsetUnset('vatendimento');
    $dadosForm = $this->request->offsetUnset('integra');
    $dadosForm = $this->request->offsetUnset('material');
```

(For reference PHP will return a NULL value from functions which don't specify a return - as *offsetUnset* doesn't.)  I believe you're intending to do something more like:

```
    $this->request->offsetUnset('fat_cnpj');
    $this->request->offsetUnset('vatendimento');
    $this->request->offsetUnset('integra');
    $this->request->offsetUnset('material');

    $dadosForm = $this->request->except('_token');
```

Comment: Changed the error now the error is in the Array below  Column not found